# Let $f(x) =|x|+|x+1|+...+|x+99|$ then find: $f'\left(\frac{-9}{2}\right)=?$

Tags: calculus

> Let $f(x) =|x|+|x+1|+...+|x+99|$ then find :
>
> $$f'\left(\frac{-9}{2}\right)=?$$

---

My Try :

$$\lim_{x\to \frac{-9}{2}}\dfrac{f(x)-f\left(\frac{-9}{2}\right)}{\left(x+\frac{9}{2}\right)}
=
\lim_{x\to \frac{-9}{2}}\dfrac{(90x+95(52)-10)-f\left(\frac{-9}{2}\right)}
{\left(x+\frac{9}{2}\right)}
=?
$$

Now what ?

Comment: Can you find the derivative of $|x+k|$ at $-\frac 92$?

Comment: Or can you find a simpler expression for $f(x)$ for $x \in (-5, -4)$?

Comment: Use $|x + k|' = \operatorname{sign}(x + k)$. For $|x + 4|$ and below derivative is $-1$ at $-9/2$ and from $|x+5|$ onwards derivative is $1$ at $-9/2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Calculate $f(x)$ explicitly (without the moduli) in a small enough neighbourhood around $-9/2$, and then differentiate directly.

Answer (score 1):

we have $f(x)=\left| x\right| +\left| x+1\right| +\left| x+2\right| +\left| x+3\right| +\left| x+4\right|+\ldots +\left| x+99\right|$

In the interval $\left[-4.6,-4.4\right]$ the function is

$f(x)=-x-x-1-x-2-x-3-x-4+(x+5)+(x+6)+(x+7)+(x+8)+(x+9) +\ldots+x+99$

the first $10$ terms containing $-x$ and $x$ simplify to $25$ while the other $90$ give

$f(x)=90x+M$

differentiating will give $f'(-9/2)=90$

Hope this helps